# Achartengine dynamic plot - strange plotting behavior

Tags: android, achartengine

I am using Achartengine to create a LineChart that plots some random data at a specific time interval.

Here is my code:

```
    myPlotView = (MyPlotView)view.findViewById(R.id.myplotview);

    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("Test Series");
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    multipleSeriesRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setChartTitle("Test Plot");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setXTitle("Number of Points");
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setShowLegend(false);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.setShowGrid(false);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setColor(Color.GREEN);
    multipleSeriesRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    myChart = new org.achartengine.chart.LineChart(dataset, multipleSeriesRenderer);
    myPlotView.setChart(myChart);

    Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            while (true) {
                XYSeries series = myChart.getDataset().getSeriesAt(0);
                int itemCount = series.getItemCount();
                series.append(itemCount+1, (float)(Math.random() * 100));
                myPlotView.repaint();
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(200);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    t.start();
```

Everything plots fine for awhile but there comes a point like around 500 points where it suddenly stops rendering any points on the chart, although the x-axis continues to increase.

This continues until the already drawn points reach about halfway: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jt4AI.png)

At which point all the "missing points" suddenly all get rendered to the screen at once. (https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5XJ9.png)

This pattern then continues throughout the life of the plot.

Is this the expected behavior? Is there anyway to fix this so that the points always get rendered to the chart as they get added?

It looks really strange when it's not plotting as it seems like the chart is "stuck".

Comment: I suggest you try the newest version available here: http://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/org/achartengine/achartengine/1.2.0/ and let me know if you can still see the issue.

Comment: Looks like the issue is fixed with the new version.  Thanks Dan.